# used a variable table'name in FMDB

Tags: ios

I use variable table'name in database!such as:

```
BOOL judge=[self.database executeUpdate:@"insert into
?(id,name,headimg,excerpt,postion) values
(?,?,?,?,?)",tableName,aID,aName,aImg,aExcept,aCoor];
```

but this 'insert into' not function! I don't how to do

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use tablename as variable you can try the following

```
NSString *sql=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into %@ (id,name,headimg,excerpt,postion) values (%@,%@,%@,%@,%@)",tablename,aID,aName,aImg,aExcept,aCoor];

BOOL judge=[self.database executeUpdate:sql];
```

Comment: tablename can't use a variable ?

Comment: not as prepared statement.. But yes if you want to use the tablename as variable you can create your query as formatted string.. that would also work..

Comment: I　don't know how to use ,could  you tell me??

Comment: BOOL判断= [self.database的executeUpdate：@“插入？（ID，的名称，headimg，摘录，现在的位置）值（，，，，？）”，表名，援助源自：AName，aImg，aExcept，aCoor ]我用这个方法吧！  but it's no fuction.I don't know I how to do

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into '%@' (id,name,headimg,excerpt,postion) values (%d,'%@','%@','%@','%@')",tableName,aID,aName,aImg,aExcept,aCoor];

BOOL judge=[self.database executeUpdate:query];
```

Also change the format specifiers according to your need. (Probably id is so used %d, other variables are taken as Strings so used %@)

Comment: I used this method but it's no fuction

Comment: @willBetter: Please NSLog the query and check that is correct or not.

Comment: I used this method ,It's ok!!just now,thank you.my english is not good

Answer (score 0):

The way I'm doing it keeps SQLite binding at work :)

```
NSString * queryString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM %@ ",[self modelDatabaseTableName]];
queryString = [queryString stringByAppendingString:@"WHERE UUID = ?;"];
FMResultSet *existenceCheckResultSet = [database executeQuery:queryString,[modelObject valueForKey:@"UUID"]];
```

Hope it helps.

Giova