# Bind parameter in FROM clause in SQLite

Tags: ios, sqlite, mobile, fmdb

Is it possible to bind a parameter in the FROM clause of a query to SQLite? How?

If not, why? Any alternatives?

Here is what I want to do in my iOS application:

```
- (BOOL)existsColumn:(NSString *)column inTable:(NSString *)table ofDatabase:(FMDatabase *)database {
    NSString *query = @"SELECT ? FROM ? LIMIT 0";
    NSArray *queryParameters = @[column, table];
    return (BOOL)[database executeQuery:query withArgumentsInArray:queryParameters];
}
```

Here is the error message I get:

> near "?": syntax error

I understand that there are other ways to [check if a column exists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2520945/1529675). I am specifically curious why I can't bind a parameter in the FROM clause (only binding a parameter in the SELECT clause above works so it must be an issue with the FROM clause).

Comment: Here my solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23834316/428143

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `?` should only be used for binding actual values into the query such in the `VALUES` section of an `INSERT` or values in a `WHERE` clause.

For dynamically building the column and table names you should simply use a string format to build the query string before sending it to FMDB.

```
- (BOOL)existsColumn:(NSString *)column inTable:(NSString *)table ofDatabase:(FMDatabase *)database {
    NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT %@ FROM %@ LIMIT 0", column, table];
    return (BOOL)[database executeQuery:query];
}
```

Please note that you should not use the string format in place of using `?` and proper value binding for actual values (which you don't have in this case).